# Automatically retrieve a specific file via SFTP

Tags: sftp, files, file-transfer

How do I determine which file is the newest from a remote server that I am connected to via SFTP?
My goal is to retrieve a specific file each day, via SFTP. The steps I will follow are:

1. Connect to server via SFTP
2. Retrieve the name of the file I need **<-- need help with this step**
3. Download it

I can figure out how to connect via SFTP from a script but I am not sure about the best way to go about determining which file to download.

For example, there are many files on the server named like so:

```
ABC-Alpha-Sun-May-12-abc123.xml.gz
ABC-Beta-Sun-May-12-abc123.xml.gz
```

I want to retrieve only that day's Alpha file. I assume that I would check the name for "May-12" to know if this is today's file? Or perhaps I should be checking the file creation date or modified date?

How would I actually retrieve the filename? Perhaps I retrieve the names of all of the files and then sort them somehow?

What would you recommend as the best way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

With WinSCP, it's easy. You can use the [`-latest` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#latest) of the [`get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get) in [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting).

Also, in case your preferred scripting language is PowerShell, you can also consider using WinSCP .NET assembly with its [`Session.ListDirectory` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory).

There are an example on WinSCP site, for all these approaches to [downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*