# sftp: get file by mtime

Tags: unix, shell, sftp, csv

**Objective:**

Connect to sftp server with very simple script using -b option, cd to directory and get file with the latest modified time or created time.

I can connect and download *.csv but that may download a dozen; I can provide part of the file name but that changes monthly, so I think the best solution is mtime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look to sftp manual ([sftp(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/sftp.1?query=sftp&sec=1)) you can see there is a way to perform a ls sorting by mtime (ls -t). So you can run sftp twice:

First time you perform a `ls -lt` (or `ls -lrt` to reverse order) redirect the output to a file and just read the last line of listing, so you have the filename, and on the second round you can specify the file to download.

Comment: Make sense but how do I re-direct output? ls -lrt > `alphamikevictor
Can't ls: "/usr/home/aaa/u/zzz/>" not found`

Comment: When you launch the SFTP `sftp -b listfiles.sftp > files_listed.log` (being listfiles.sftp your batch file)

Comment: Just linking to a similiar question I didn't find last night: http://serverfault.com/questions/507394/automatically-retrieve-a-specific-file-via-sftp